# Is there a way to continue a "Survival: Endless" game?

Tags: ios, plants-vs-zombies

Is there a way to continue a "Survival: Endless" game?  I am up to flag 27, but carelessly lose the level... Do I have to start all over from flag 1 to flag 27 again?  That's very tiring!

(**Update:** actually, I thought of a way on PC or Mac, which is to install the game on a virtual PC, so we have a "snapshot" of the hard drive.  We can just quit the game, and save any number of copies of the virtual hard drive, and be able to start the game as on that drive's image.... but probably we can save some data file instead of the whole hard drive).

At flag 27, I forgot to include a Coffee Bean to wake up Ice-Shroom and Doom-Shroom and the Gargantuar and Giga-Gargantuar will end the level right there -- even invoking the Lawn Mowers first, and then a second wave wil end the game.  I usually pack the Lily Pad, Doom-Shroom, and Coffee Bean first, and then Ice-Shroom and an Imitator Ice-Shroom, but sometimes I have to do repair work and then forgot to pack something.

I am playing the iPad version (version 1.9.4 as of June 2012).  The set up I am using is the cobless one:

(by the way, what is the "white flower" on the ground at the right side of the lawn?)

Answer (score 2):

No matter which wave you lose at, you have to restart from the beginning. Also, the white flowers are daisies and have no purpose but to be an easter egg (type daisies on your keyboard -- I don't know how to achieve it on iPad).